# Android claims that I have misspelled something in XML

Tags: xml, android

I need to use various words but it seems that Android plays nanny and says that they are misspelled in XML.

```
<string name="oiseau">oiseau</string>
```

How do I override this function?  TIA.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the eclipse spell checker, not android.  Is it complaining and not compiling/deploying your project, or just showing the squiggly lines under the word?  To turn off spell checking in eclipse go to:

Window->preferences->general->editors->text editors->spelling and you can disable this.  Or add the words to a dictionary you define.